# Signature verification fails when trying to sign transaction with a delegate accout

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, javascript

I am trying to sign a transaction using a delegate account, but transaction.verifySignature() always returns false. However, the transaction works perfectly when I sign it with the owner's keypair. Here's a little reference to my code.

```
// delegate the ATA to delegate authority
await approve(connection,owner,ataAddress,delegateAuthority.publicKey,owner.publicKey,3000)

//build swap tx
tx = buildSwapTransaction(params)
tx.sign(delegateAuthority)
console.log(tx.verifySignature)
```

**This particular chunk of code returns false for delegate keypair and true for owner's keypair**

*P.S. I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to do*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out that when sending a transfer instruction using delegate account, **you have to specify the delegate account as both the signer and the owner**. Previously, I was specifying the actual owner as the owner in transaction, and was then trying to sign transaction with delegate keypair. This was causing the transaction to fail.